# ¿Cómo explicar el uso del subjuntivo en esta frase?

Tags: subjuntivo

> La calle era discreta **a pesar de que** las tantas ventanas de su nombre **hicieran** pensar en demasiados ojos detrás de los visillos.

Comment: ¿Por qué no habría de tener subjuntivo?

Comment: ... xq normalmente va con el indicativo ¿no?.. "a pesar de q", digo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El subjuntivo cuesta de entender a los no nativos. Por experiencia con mi mujer, cuando se les explica en clase se les dice que `The subjunctive is not a tense; rather, it is a mood`.

Si usases el indicativo estarías indicando que es más o menos objetivo que muchas las ventanas de esa calle hacen pensar en ojos que te observan.

> La calle es discreta a pesar de que las tantas ventanas de su nombre **hacen** pensar en demasiados ojos detrás de los visillos.

Pero como tenemos ese "hacer pensar" y el sentirse observado es más una sensación que un hecho, se usa el subjuntivo;

> La calle es discreta a pesar de que las tantas ventanas de su nombre **hagan** pensar en demasiados ojos detrás de los visillos.

Puede no haber nadie detrás de las ventanas, o puede haber mucha gente. No importa. Es cómo tú te sientes (observado).

Comment: sí, x supuesto el subjuntivo es un modo y no el tiempo...