# Subjuntivo vs. Indicativo: "estación que me sirve/sirva"

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

¿Por qué en un caso se usa el subjuntivo y en el otro el indicativo?

> El bus no pasa por ninguna estación que me sirv**a**.
>
> Ninguna estación del bus me sirv**e**.
>
> No hay estación del bus que me sirv**a**.

Comment: Leyendo [esta respuesta de Diego](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14955/1674) se puede utilizar su recomendación: `The subjunctive is not a tense; rather, it is a mood`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como norma más o menos sencilla: cuando una oración subordinada se introduce mediante el relativo *que*, el verbo va en indicativo si se habla de algo concreto y conocido, en subjuntivo si no.

En tus ejemplos primero y tercero, puesto que ninguna estación sirve, no se habla de ninguna estación concreta ni conocida, así que el verbo debe ir en subjuntivo. En la segunda oración va en indicativo porque no hay subordinada.

En las oraciones negativas nunca hablamos de un caso concreto, puesto que no existe. Pero podemos tener el mismo caso en oraciones afirmativas. Por ejemplo:

> El coche que me gusta tiene llantas de aleación.
>
> El coche que me guste debe tener llantas de aleación.

En el primer caso, hay un coche concreto que me gusta, y ese coche tiene llantas de aleación.

En el segundo, digo que debe tener esa característica para poder gustarme, pero no me refiero a ninguno en concreto.

Más ejemplos:

> El primero que venga se llevará un premio.

(No sé quién será esa persona).

> El primero que viene se llama Juan.

(Estoy viendo a esa persona y hablo de ella en concreto).

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la explicación tan clara y detallada!